# Type conversion issues with inserting into unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, unordered-map

What I am trying to do is to have basically a key value store in a c++ class so that I can lookup values from it by the key. I've been trying to use an unordered_map to do it with code similar to this. (I've simplified it a little but you get the idea).

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

class manager
{
public:
manager() {}
~manager(){}

void add(const std::string& name, unsigned int val) {
    map.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, unsigned int>(name, val));
}

unsigned int GetValue(const std::string& key) {
    return map[key];
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> map;
};

int main(void)
{
manager* mgr = new manager();
mgr->add("Bob",22);

std::cout << "Bob is" << mgr->GetValue("Bob") << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

I just want to store a name and value in a way that I can easily lookup the value by name, and easily clean it up when done to avoid memory leaks.

When I compile this on Linux (g++ -o test test.cpp) I get the following:

> test.cpp: In member function ‘void manager::add(const string&,
>   unsigned int)’: test.cpp:12:65: error: no matching function for call
>   to ‘make_pair(const string&, unsigned int&)’
>   map.insert(std::make_pair(name, val));
>                                                                    ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/6/string:40,
>                    from test.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:497:5: note: candidate:
>   template constexpr std::pair::__type, typename
>   std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
>        make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
>        ^~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:497:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:12:56: note:
>   cannot convert ‘name’ (type ‘const string {aka const
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string}’) to type
>   ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string&&’
>   map.insert(std::make_pair(name, val));

Comment: You may need to include the utility header.

Comment: Why are you using `new`? What's wrong with `manager mgr; mgr.add(...);`?

Comment: How about using [] operator .  void add( const std::string& name, unsigned int val) {
    map[name]= val;
}

Comment: Was using new to get a pointer that I can pass to other methods for access as required.

Answer (score 2):

The [std::make_pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) signature is wrong. Should be:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(name, val));
```